# Get all record types with Net_DNS2

Tags: php, dns, pear

I want to retreive all record types for a domain like google.com. I was using PHP's `dns_get_record` function for this with the following piece of code.

```
$result = dns_get_record("google.com",DNS_ANY);
```

This works pretty good. It returns all records with types like A, AAAA, MX and TXT. But the `dns_get_record` function has no support for custom nameservers. I found that PEAR package Net_DNS2 does support custom nameservers so I installed that and tried to find all record types. But the `Net_DNS2_Resolver` class does not seem to support a `DNS_ANY` type. This means that I need to query all types sequentially and that more time and is more difficult to code.

Does the `Net_DNS2_Resolver` class support a wildcard type? If not, does the `query` command support an array of types? The documentation says no but maybe it's out of date or something.

How does the PHP function `dns_get_record` work? Does it do multiple request for all types in the background or is there really a way to request all types at once? If it's the first than I simply need to create my own code for requesting all record types.

Comment: Do not use the `ANY` (pseudo) record type. It will not do what you think it does, and it is on the path to be obsoleted, for the exact reason that it is not used appropriately. Indeed you should do a loop yourself on the specific record types you need. This will always work correctly, the only question being if you query the authoritative nameservers or some recursive...

Comment: Do you have any sources to proof the `ANY` record type will become absoleted? For now my question has been answered by mdeora but I would very much like to now if this query method is future proof.

Comment: See this blog article from CloudFlare: https://blog.cloudflare.com/what-happened-next-the-deprecation-of-any/  They wrote an internet-draft and there is another one that propose to have resolvers only reply with `CNAME`, `MX`, `A` and `AAAA` records to `ANY` queries, which basically means that ANY ≠ ALL anymore (it was already the case as querying ANY gives you basically the content of the cache of the resolver for the label, but the cache may not be complete at all! which is a point often forgotten)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS_ANY is supported in the latest release of net dns pear package. 
Check link below - 
http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2/docs/latest/Net_DNS2/Net_DNS2_RR_ANY.html#methodrrGet